# PhoneBootStrapper namespace in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, github, namespaces, nuget

I'm trying to use [MuPDF](https://github.com/MishaUliutin/MuPDF.WinRT) from Github for Windows phone 8. The Author `MishaUliutin` mentioned about sample project in a [comment](https://github.com/MishaUliutin/MuPDF.WinRT/issues/22#issuecomment-46151712) of issue. So I downloaded Repository code from [here](https://bitbucket.org/mishauliutin/pdf-reader-for-wp8-public/downloads).

I tried to build the project but I am getting error  `namespace 'PhoneBootstrapper' could not be found` on `PhoneBootstrapper` class. I'm not sure about the PhoneBootstrapper class or Is there any thing else that I'm missing.

[image]

**Edit:**

- I tried to add the downloaded project to another new project using Add existing project option and then try to add reference from solution it gives the fallowing error in image.
- For this I unblocked the dll file suggested from here  http://vkslabs.com/reference-higher-version-incompatible-assembly-added-project/ (*not working*)

[image]

**&** 
 - I downloaded the sample project from Here [ https://bitbucket.org/mishauliutin/pdf-reader-for-wp8-public/downloads ]
 - And sample project itself having a Solution file(.sln).
 - I try build it & gives me the `PhoneBootstrapper` error.

So.. I believe `phoneBootstapper` is class from [Caliburn.Micro](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Caliburn.Micro/) which is added as nuget package to the project.

Comment: are you missing the using directive? right click PhoneBootsstrapper -> resolve -> Using namespace.blabla. are you missing the using directive? right click PhoneBootsstrapper -> resolve -> Using namespace.blabla Hmm after looking better it seems you're using a winRT library on a Windows phone project which are separate thinks that cannot work togheter. See whether there is a Windows phone versione of the library. Third edit: after  seeing the site you provided I guess you probably are using the correct library for WP8, but my first might still be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for comment. BTW there is no namespace referring for PhoneBottsstrapper class http://i.stack.imgur.com/W7mSA.png & I didn't understand your last line.

Comment: I would like to know reason for the downvote; Thanks

Comment: do you have referenced both the .winmd and the .dll? I had to use winmd only once and I remember that had to reference both in order to make it work.

Comment: @FabioMarcolini  I didn't add the reference. Before adding reference I want to build it download project. I edit the question by adding details of what I tried so far